# Enabling graphics acceleration for OpenGL over remotely via VPN from Ubuntu client(my laptop)to Windows server(computation is here)

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, graphics, opengl, hardware-acceleration

I have an access to Internet via a Wifi.

Then, I have a VPN connection established from my Ubuntu laptop to a LAN network. In that network there is my Windows Machine where computation happens using OpenGL. It is for visualization.

After establishing the VPN connection from my Ubuntu Laptop to the LAN network, I used rdesktop (and other remote desktop clients like KRDC) to run the program on the Windows machine. It fails, because of rdesktop or others not supporting certain graphics hardware acceleration via remote desktop, being transferred from the Windows Machine back to my Ubuntu Laptop for remote client on Ubuntu to see/visualize. Errors like "Shaders not supported..." Please find the link to the image as well.
[The error message](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4ANGiZjMV69VkFHeFp4YVU0bGM)

How can I solve this, please ?

After Googling, I arrived at the possibilities ..

Should I use team viewer ?

It had earlier worked comfortably from a MAC OS laptop to the Windows Machine. Is it a good idea to set up MAC OS virtually on my Ubuntu laptop and then establish VPN and remote desktop via virtual MAC ?

Can VirtualGL help ?

Comment: Teamviewer Works !!